# The usage of as+adjective

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between two sentences below

1. The expression would not sound **scientific**
2. The expression would not sound **as** **scientific**

I wonder the difference when using as in front of adjective

Comment: The difference is that it would become a comparative construction, i.e. "as scientific as something else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of the second sentence like this :

The expression would not sound as scientific **(as the expression that was mentioned before)**